# Insert Function using strcmp()

Tags: c, string, linked-list, nodes, strcmp

I'm trying to make an insert function, but I don't know if I'm allowed to used a char string and a node in the argument.

Does this work? Why not?

```
    void insert(char* str, node* head) {
      if (head == NULL) {
        node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        assert(new_node != NULL);
        new_node->value = strdup(str);
    }
    while (head != NULL) {
      if (strcmp(str, head->value)) {
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struc node));
        assert(new_node != NULL);
        new_node->link = head;
        new_node->value - strdup(str);
      }
    }
    node *prev = head;
    head = head->link;
```

Comment: "Does this work?" Test it and you will know. Not so easy to see if that works by just looking at the code - unless you are a real expert.

Comment: This is also not all the code.  You're the only one who has enough of the code to know if it works or not.

Comment: Notice that `head = head->link;` modifies the value of `head` in the scope of the function, but not outside of it. Functions work on copies of arguments. To solve this, pass `head` by pointer, even if it is already a pointer. Try `void insert(char* str, node** head)` and `if(*head==NULL)...`

Comment: If `head` is null on entry, you can't change anything in the calling function, so the next time the code is called `head` will still be null, so you'll be leaking memory.  There are endless questions about this on SO.  You either need to pass a pointer to a `node *` to the function, or have the function return the (new) head pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havet to return the new head of the list by return value. If you insert one node you have to allocate memory for one node. Don't forget the initialize member `prev` of the first node and the member `link` of the last node with `NULL`:

```
node* insert(char* str, node* head)
{
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    assert(new_node != NULL);
    new_node->value = strdup(str);
    new_node->link = NULL;          // successor of new node is NULL

    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        new_node->pev = NULL;       // prdecessor of first node is NULL
        head = new_node;   
        return new_node;            // head was NULL, return new head
    }

    node *lastNode = head;          // go to last node of list
    while ( head->link != NULL )
        lastNode = lastNode->link;  // step one forward

    lastNode->link = new_node;      // successor of last node is new node
    new_node->prev = lastNode;      // predecesor of new node is last node
    return head;
}
```

-

```
node *head = NULL;
head = insert( "abc", head );
head = insert( "def", head );
```

An other solution would be to use an in and output paramter for your paramter `head` in function `insert`:

```
void insert(char* str, node** head)
                        // ^^ in and output parameter
{
  node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  assert(new_node != NULL);
  new_node->value = strdup(str);
  new_node->link = NULL;          // successor of new node is NULL

  node* prev = NULL;
  node* act = *head;
  while ( act != NULL )           // go to last node in list
  {
      prev = act;
      act = act->link;            // step one forward
  }

  new_node->prev = prev;     // predecessor of new node is last node or NULL
  if ( prev == NULL )
      *head = new_node;      // new node is the first node in list,
                             //   write the new node back to head
  else
      prev->link = new_node; // successor of last node is new node
}
```

-

```
node *head = NULL;
insert( "abc", &head );
insert( "def", &head );
```